# Java Threads release properly

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread which uses a connection pool connection and executes query on the db which runs for around 1 min. before 1 min if user logs out of the application this thread just goes in an infinite loop and never releases.
how can I ensure that when user clicks on logout button all threads will be killed?

Answer (score 0):

When user logs out, set a flag to `false`. This flag should be checked by the thread to stop running ahead.

Showing some code will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a shutdown hook to your main class which is creating threads.

Just giving an example here :

Add this line in main class:

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Message());

static class Message extends Thread {

```
       public void run() {
           System.out.println("Bye.");
           try {
            // do your work here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to keep track of the threads you launch, and the components that launch threads themselves.

Secondly, you need to shut these down properly. For threads that poll/loop, you need to exit those loops (perhaps by setting flags). You also need to *interrupt* threads that may be waiting on I/O, and handle that interrupt properly. See [this article from Java Specialist](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html) for info on this often-misunderstood issue (basically, reset the interrupt flag on the interrupted thread...)